# iOS "corrupting" PHP Session

Tags: php, ios, session

I have been working on a bug now that has been plaguing me for ages and it is really obscure and difficult to get to the bottom of.

- The bug only affects iOS devices (iPhone/iPad)
- It won't always affect a device, it seems to be random
- Customers who have placed several orders fine may suddenly experience it, then when placing another order minutes later not experience it
- We have seen it happen in both very old devices and newer versions of iOS
- It only affects users using Safari that we have seen

Theories we have tested:

- Something to do with mobile data/switching between cell towers when roaming causes the session to become corrupt. We were unable to reproduce this and customers experiencing it say it has happened while at home on WiFi
- When switching between HTTP/HTTPS the session is becoming void, we made the entire site secure and it still happened
- Poor code in our cart somewhere, we operate multiple brands and some are using different carts. A similar thing happens in all of them
- Server misconfiguration, tried multiple servers with 4 different hosts. They configured the server in 2 instances with the same result.
- The payment gateway isn't working correctly (we used to use a HPP & PayPal solution), we switched to an API solution with the same result
- Somehow misconfigured product, can't be the case as the same product works fine in almost all cases, except the odd iOS ones

Below I have included a sample of what the array should look like storing the cart, and what it looks like on a corrupt iOS cart

**Correct Cart**

```
$_SESSION['cart'] = array(
'items' = array (0  => array(
                    'product_name'      => 'Shirt',
                    'product_price'     => '20.00',
                    'product_sku'       => '801245',
                    'vat_rate'          => '20.0000',

                    'attributes'        => array(
                                                    'size'      =>  array('value' => 'large',   'cost' => '+5'),
                                                    'qty'       =>  array('value' => 1,         'cost' => '+0'),
                                                    'colour'    =>  array('value' => 'blue',    'cost' => '+0'),
                                                    ),

                    'delivery_info'     => array(
                                                    'name'      => 'Mr A. Tester',
                                                    'line1'     => 'Street',
                                                    'line2'     => 'Off another street',
                                                    'company'   => 'ACME Ent.',
                                                    'postcode'  => 'AA1 0AA',
                                                    'county'    => 'London',
                                                    'country'   => 'United Kingdom',
                                                    'date'      => '2015-12-01',
                                                    ),
                    )
                ),

'totals' = array    (
                    'item'          => '20.00',
                    'extras'        => '5.00',
                    'delivery'      => '3.00',
                    'blended_vat'   => '20.0000',
                    'to_pay'        => '28.00',
                    ),

'cart_id'       =   'fc5e038d38a57032085441e7fe7010b0',
'customer_id'   =   '102145',
'order_status'  =   'Pending',
'paid'          =   false,
```

)

**Corrupt iOS Cart**

```
$_SESSION['cart'] = array(
'items' = array (

                    'attributes'        => array(
                                                    'size'      =>  array('value' => 'large',   'cost' => '+5'),
                                                    'qty'       =>  array('value' => 1,         'cost' => '+0'),
                                                    'colour'    =>  array('value' => 'blue',    'cost' => '+0'),
                                                    ),

                    'delivery_info'     => array(
                                                    'name'      => 'Mr A. Tester',
                                                    'line1'     => 'Street',
                                                    'line2'     => 'Off another street',
                                                    'company'   => 'ACME Ent.',
                                                    'postcode'  => 'AA1 0AA',
                                                    'county'    => 'London',
                                                    'country'   => 'United Kingdom',
                                                    'date'      => '2015-12-01',
                                                    ),
                    )
                ),
0   => array(
                    'product_name'      => 'Shirt',
                    'product_price'     => '20.00',
                    'product_sku'       => '801245',
                    'vat_rate'          => '20.0000',

'totals' = array    (
                    'item'          => '20.00',
                    'extras'        => '5.00',
                    'delivery'      => '3.00',
                    'blended_vat'   => '20.0000',
                    'to_pay'        => '28.00',
                    ),

'cart_id'       =   'fc5e038d38a57032085441e7fe7010b0',
'customer_id'   =   '102145',
'order_status'  =   'Pending',
'paid'          =   false,
```

)

I would love to hear anyone's thoughts on this and any possible suggestions. As I say the cart works fine with every OS/Browser combination. It only randomly seems to affect iPhones/iPads, and could work fine on the same device several times, then not work, then work again.

It seems random as to when it won't work.

Comment: Sessions are stored and managed by server-side code. Which means that if something wrong happens, then it's your php code that is responsible for that.

Comment: Yeah I appreciate that. Which is the main reason I can't understand this issue.

How is it possible that the server can handle the sessions fine for all but these 2 use cases?
But then also within these 2 uses cases it could work perfectly fine for say 10 orders, order 11 fails, but order 12 works?

Does iOS somehow handle session ID's differently?

Comment: "Does iOS somehow handle session ID's differently?" --- it's not possible to do that. It's your code that breaks it somehow.